# setState slower then callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am using some callback function (firebase), the issue that this callback function can be trigger more than once, the issue when I am using setState inside call back then sometimes its not finish to set first state and set the second. that making the setstate without updated data,
This is my code:

```
 commentsRef.on("child_changed", (data) => {
     
        if (guests) {
          const key = data.key;
          const updatedGuest = data.val();
//guests ->isnt updated from last trigger
          const cloneGuests =_.cloneDeep(guests);
          cloneGuests.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (element.guestID === key) {
              cloneGuests[index] = updatedGuest;
            }
          });
          setGuests(cloneGuests);
        }
      });
```